# Mvvmcross nested view models

Tags: c#, mvvm, viewmodel, mvvmcross

So I have a view and I would like to be able to nest multiple views in it based on the user selection and I would like each nested view to have its own viewmodel and to be loaded dynamically when the user select it because I have a lot of nested views, I think that mvvcross can not do that by defaults but is there a workaround?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I don't believe that nesting lots of views are a good practice on mvvmcross nor xamarin forms either

Comment: @FabriBertani I want to achieve something like a tab view but load the view dynamically instead of putting all of them in the xaml as I have lots of views and putting them all in xaml would be inefficient, also please note that I am using wpf  not xamarin.forms

Comment: look at the existing questions. i think this was already answered.